# Can sed insert text with newlines into other text?

Tags: bash, sed, newline

Is sed capable of inserting text B into the middle of text A if B has newlines?

I found examples of how to insert text into the middle of other text using sed - but the only such examples I could find were where the inserted text was a one-liner.

I'm unable to determine the syntax (or even the possibility) of inserting text into other text if the inserted text has newlines. Can anyone help?

I'm not married to sed. I'm okay with any solution, but I am also curious if this can be done with sed.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
>c1="$(cat f1)"
>echo "$c1"
a
b
c
d
>c2="$(cat f2)"
>echo "$c2"
x
y
z
>echo "$c1" | sed "s,^c,c\n"${c2}","
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
>echo "$c1" | sed "s,^c,c\n${c2},"
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

Thank you.

Comment: Change `\n` by `^M` (obtained with CTRL-V, CTRL-M).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your specific case you could use `sed`'s `r` command which reads a file and adds its content to the output stream :

```
sed '/^c/r f2' f1
```

This should be equivalent to your  `echo "$c1" | sed "s,^c,c\n"${c2}","` attempt, adding the content of the `f2` file after the line starting with `c`.

Note that I don't use the `s`ubstitute command but rather test each line with `/^c/` and execute the `r`ead command for each line matching.

Comment: How interesting. Your solution worked. I'll have to study up on this sed option. Thank you.

Comment: `sed` has many more commands than its well known `s` one, but from experience you can go years without ever discovering them :) At least check the `/test/` syntax, it's especially useful to delete specific lines (`/test/d`) or do multiple actions on a specific line (e.g. `/test/{N;s/pattern/repl/}` for a two-line replacement)